# Python: Subclass AttributeError

Tags: python, subclass, parent, attributeerror

Python 3.5.2
I'm having some funny problem with my subclass, when trying to access parent field. There are three classes.(Command->Newarticle->Editarticle). The code is roughly like this, I've deleted additional methods, to minimize the code amount):

```
class Command(object):
    __metaclass__=abc.ABCMeta ;
    def __init__(self):
        # set default command name
        self.__name="I hate planes" ;
        self.__has_ended=False ;        

class Newarticle(Command):
    def __init__(self, modules):
        # parent init
        Command.__init__(self) ;
        self.__output=modules[MAIN_OUTPUT] ;
        self.__input=modules[MAIN_INPUT] ;

class Editarticle(Newarticle):
    def __init__(self, modules):
        Newarticle.__init__(self, modules) ;
        #super().__init__(modules) ;

        print(dir(self)) ;

        # ERROR HAPPENS HERE !
        self.__output.use_random_function() ;
```

I know for sure that there is MAIN_OUTPUT in modules, because Newarticle works perfectly. 
The error text: AttributeError: 'Editarticle' object has no attribute '_Editarticle__output'

The print out of 'dir' is: ['_Command__has_ended', '_Command__name', '_Editarticle__acc_data', '_Editarticle__art_id', '_Newarticle__art_images', '_Newarticle__art_name', '_Newarticle__art_text', '_Newarticle__db_mod', '_Newarticle__input', '**_Newarticle__output**', '_Newarticle__run_subcmds', '_Newarticle__tag_reader',...] and etc.

So the problem is clear, Python adds Class names before the methods, and is not trying even to look up in parent. So how do I fix it? I feel blind for not seeing where is the problem.

P.S. I've tried to call the 'super()', instead of 'Newarticle.**init**(self, modules)', absolutely same result. 
P.S.P.S. I've tried to remove the metaclass ABC from first parent('Command'), same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using double underscore prefixes, which invokes name mangling. Don't do that. These are very rarely useful.

Just use normal names for your attributes;

```
def __init__(self):
    # set default command name
    self.name = "I hate planes"
    self.has_ended = False
```

(Also, please remove those semicolons. They are not used in Python.)

Comment: Yeah, big thanks!!! I had the feeling about the underscore prefixes. It's a shame though, really needed to distinguish different groups of attributes, seems I will have to find another road.

Comment: Oh, and don't worry about the semicolons. I know that Python community sees them as bane of existence. But ... Python allows them! And it's so wonderful for me, I program in c++, PHP, java... and other languages where it's required so much, that semicolon after statement is a pure finger reflex. And for my own comprehension, I feel disturbed when there is none. So thank you Python for allowing it for such people like me.

Comment: Anyone having to maintain your code will hate you for the semicolons - and I do use other languages that requires them too so bad habit is not an excuse ;)

Comment: @TadasBaikshtis More seriously: if you want to express that an attribute or method is an implementation detail and not part of the public API, just prefix it with a single underscore. That's the convention for what is usually known as "protected".

Comment: Yeah, I switched yesterday to "protected" mentality. Thanks anyway.
Oh and please, don't worry about semicolons, as I said, that's my personal thing for my personal comfort.